# how does one line up a responsive center column of specific width?

Tags: css, html, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hate asking a "how do I do this" question, but I've tried everything I can think of and it's just not working.

I have a page design in which there is a center column of specific width (960px) which needs to live in the horizontal center of the page as long as the browser is wider than that width.

I'm entirely unclear on why, but every combination of columns and offsets I try leaves the content off center in one way or another.

I know how to do this with margin:auto but then I lose bootstrap's auto-magical resizing of everything for mobile.

So... is there a way to keep the responsive nature of the site as per bootstrap but to have it put the content into a center strip of a specific width (leaving the sides empty) and yet collapsing down to the -xs- variant when the page is pulled up on mobile?

Comment: if you wrap in bootstrap `container` it should center

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to use is the bootstrap container, you can view the docs about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

it is as simple as:

```
<div class="container">
..some content..
</div>
```